# Application of Opening Mapping theorem

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ be a holomorphic function on open set $A$ such that $(Im(f(z))^3 + (Re(f(z))^4 =5.$ Could anyone advise me on how to use Open mapping theorem to prove $f$ is constant? Hints will suffice. Thank you.

Comment: You need to assume $A$ is both open and connected.  Otherwise, if you have two disconnected components of $A$, you can define $f(z) = 5^{1/4}$ in the first component, and $f(z) = i5^{1/3}$ in the second.

Comment: You might determine if the image of $f$ is open or not.

Comment: Noted. So we need to show $\{(x,y): x^4 + y^3 = 5\}$ is not open?

Comment: If you can show that, then...

Comment: I am still trying to show...

Comment: One other detail is that the image may only be a subset of the set you gave.

Answer (score 0):

Assume $f$ is not constant on the domain $\Omega\subset{\mathbb C}$. Then there is a point $z_0\in \Omega$ with
$f'(z_0)\ne0$, and $f$ maps a suitable neighborhood $U$ of $z_0$ bijectively onto a *full neighborhood* $V$ of the point  $f(z_0)=:u_0+iv_0$.

By assumption the point $(u_0,v_0)$ lies on the set $$\gamma:=\{u+iv\>|\>u^4+v^3=5\}\ .$$
The set $\gamma$ is a level set of the function $\phi(u,v):=u^4+v^3$. Since $\nabla\phi(u,v)=(4u^3,3v^2)$ is $\ne(0,0)$ for all points $(u,v)\in\gamma$, the implicit function theorem tells us that there is a window $$W:=[u_0-h,u_0+h]\times[v_0-h,v_0+h],\qquad h>0,$$ and a function $$\psi:\quad[u_0-h,u_0+h]\to [v_0-h,v_0+h],\qquad u\mapsto v=\psi(u),$$ 
$\bigl($or a similar function $v\mapsto u=\chi(v)\bigr)$ such that
$\psi(u_0)=v_0$ and $$\gamma\cap W=\{\bigl(u,\psi(u)\bigr)\>\bigm|\>u_0-h\leq u\leq u_0+h\bigr\}\ .$$
It follows that $V$ contains points not on $\gamma$, e.g., the points $(u_0,v_0+\delta)$ for sufficiently small $\delta>0$, contrary to assumption about $f$.

Comment: why so complicated?  Also, it seems the asker is only asking for some hints, not a full answer.

Comment: @Michael: We all know that $\gamma$ is a curve and does not contain any open set; but I had the impression the OP wanted a proof of this.